# How to validate an input field if value is not null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

I am trying to create and update users with laravel 5.4

This is the validation added for create user. It works.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

On update the password field is not required. But validate the min:6 and confirmed rule if the password field is not null. Tried with `sometimes`.. but not working..

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$id,
    'password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

Comment: If you have 2 seperated functions for create and update you could remove the password validation rule from update

Answer (score 58, accepted):

try using nullable as a rule

```
'password' => 'nullable|min:6|confirmed',
```

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields

Answer (score 10):

#### In case column is nullable

```
'password' => 'nullable|min:6|confirmed',
```

@Rejinderi's answer is correct!

#### In case column is not nullable (This may help other)

```
'password' => 'sometimes|required|min:6|confirmed',
```

#### Result

```
username = 'admin',
password = null // fail- required

username = 'admin',
password = 123 // fail- min:6

username = 'admin' // pass- validate only exist
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
//For new or create :
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
]);

//For edit or update:
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'min:6|confirmed',//just remove required from password rule
]);
```

**Explanation:**
This way the value will be validated only when it will be defined (present) in request
If you use **nullable**, than validator will accept ***null*** as value (which i assume is not acceptable)
If you remove **password** validation from update than this input will not be validated at all, and **any value** will be accepted (which is again not acceptable);

Comment: Read the question carefully before answering.

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this also using Validator Class's sometimes method as per [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#complex-conditional-validation)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

//... your code ...

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'name' => 'required',
      'contact' => 'required',
]);
$validator->sometimes('password', 'min:6|confirmed', function ($input) {
    return (strlen($input->password) > 0);
});
if ($validator->fails()) {
     return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

this will validate password attribute rules when password field's **length is greater than 0.** otherwise will ignore that password attribute's rule.